# Regression LSTM output values centering around the range of the labels

Tags: python, c++, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My problem is specifically that my output values center between the min and max of the labels.

(ie: label range = min(0.20) max(0.80), output = consistently around 0.40, with small deviations)

My model specification are as such:

```
activations = All tanh, or all Relu.    
outputs = 1, inputs = 2, "cells" = 100, layers = 1.  
regularization = either L2 or L1.   
optimizer = SGD with momentum.
```

(Custom model, not built from any libraries)

my model is based off of this model : https://medium.com/@aidangomez/let-s-do-this-f9b699de31d9

Regardless of the number of epochs I do, the output stays centered around the range of labels. (it reaches this state at around 1000 epochs and stays here even until 200000 epochs. the error reaches a certain small value at this point (1000 epochs, in my case error reaches around 0.00135) and stays around here for the remaining time, decreasing at a very slow pace, even increasing eventually). The smaller I make my learning rate, the longer it takes to reach this range value and error value. but no improvement beyond.

I know there is a probability that the net simply is not "smart" enough. but the same results occur if I use 2 layers instead of 1.
But other than that, what could be causing this? just looking for pointers, Am not asking for a full model evaluation. If anyone would like the code to take a deeper look, I will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this definitively, but there are two things I would suggest you check. When you say `"cells": 100`, Are you referring to your cells state size? Because for such a small input size, you might want to decrease this to 10, to begin with. If you are referring to using 100 LSTM cells then this is far too many, start with one.

For the second thing, you mentioned you are using all ReLu or all tanh activation, is this internally on the gate outputs, or externally on the cell output? If it is internally then this is incorrect as the activation functions are chosen for their gate's purpose, so make sure your gates use the following activations:

- Input activation: tanh
- Input gate: sigmoid
- Forget gate: sigmoid
- Output gate: sigmoid

If in the other case you are referring to using the activation on the cell output or maybe you are applying a fully connected tail to the outputs try swapping to a sigmoid function on the output of the network.

Comment: thank you very much! I will make these adjustments :)

Comment: to clarify: "cells" being LSTM cells or "unrolled cells". The activations were being used internally and for the output. On some other models I made, this seemed to work better than the conventional, but now I have doubts. thank you for pointing this out to me :)